# Postfix: Can it merge attachments from two emails, delete the original emails and resend as one?

Tags: postfix

As above, really - wanting to combine the attachments from two email (going to the same sender) into one email with multiple attachments. I've seen people reference milter but I don't know what I'm doing. Or if this is even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Technically possible because technically anything is possible, but incredibly complicated because that's really not how SMTP is intended to work. I'm smelling [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/); try explaining what it is you're hoping to accomplish with this, because there *has* to be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is **complicated**.

Let's start with "two emails". There are two emails. What is the time distance over which the two emails can no longer be merged together? You need to store the first email for at least that time. And, if another mail comes by within that time, you do the merge; otherwise you release the first mail, which will arrive with a delay.

So, you need to intercept *all* emails [as they arrive](https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail), check whether they are directed to a single sender, and if that sender appears in the "coalescers" list.

If these conditions are fulfilled the email is [taken off the send queue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728620/can-queued-messages-be-moved-between-postfix-servers) or, if possible, not queued at all, and stored locally (into a mbox for example, coded for the sender. It might be in a directory with the sender MD5 as a name).

Then periodically all such mboxes have to be examined. You have to do this through a cron script, there is no other practical and reliable way. Mboxes older than a certain time must be transformed back into emails and sent without further delay.

If, saving an email, the relative mbox is already present, you [extract attachments from the incoming email](https://superuser.com/questions/187106/extract-save-a-mail-attachment-using-bash) and add it to the existing mbox.

Comment: running a dedicated mailing list for this one "subscriber" in digest mode would be a simple (but ugly) way to do this.   I'm assuming that when the OP says "sender", they actually mean "recipient" because it makes no sense to say "two email (going **to** the same sender)"

Comment: sorry, yes, I did mean recipient. oops